Configuring SSI in MAMP7
In MAMP6 (which used Apache 2.4.54), configuring server side includes could be done by modifying the httpd.conf file and adding
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html

However, in MAMP7 (Apache 2.4.58), this does not seem to work.
Checking Apache Server Information (Tools > Apache > Info in MAMP7), has the same info as in MAMP6:
In file: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf
 626: AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
 632: TypesConfig /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/mime.types
...
 675: AddType text/html .shtml
 676: AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
 677: AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html



Thanks to this StackOverflow answer:
Apache Error Log - an unknown filter was not added: includes
It led me to the Settings dialog, Server tab, where I had to check "include_module" and restart Apache.  Once that was done, SSI worked!
